# Loop function depends on pattern

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I have text

```
www.page.com
www.page1.com
www.page2.com
```

I need a function to run a specific script for specific text.
When text = www.page.com then run script 1, when page2 run script 2 when page3 then run script 3, the script I mean piece of code in the same file.

If text = www.page.com then run

```
page(){
while true; do
echo "page"
done
}
```

If text = www.page2.com then run

```
page2(){
while true; do
echo "page2"
done
}
```

If text = www.page3.com then run

```
page3(){
while true; do
echo "page3"
done
}
```

All code should be in the same script file

Files:
update_photo_list file

```
https://google.com/some/url/      >/path/to/save/
```

Thats my script

```
dl_url(){
while true; do

    while IFS='>' read -r website_url gallery_dir; do

            echo "Downloading $website_url" 
            echo "To $gallery_dir"; sleep 1
            mkdir -p ./update_photo_temp/
            wget --quiet $website_url -P ./update_photo_temp/

            ## If $website_url = to function then run function
            for i in $website_url; do
                echo $i | awk -F '/.' '{print $2}' | xargs
            done

    done < ./update_photo_list

done
}

google.com(){
while true; do
    echo "blah blah blah"
done
}
```

Its only printing the urls hostname not start proper function this should start another function depends on URL like google.com start google.com function

Comment: How are you going to pass the input? by file or runtime or array

Comment: Input is file with URLs, script should take one line check if its page.com page2.com or page3.com run specific part of script for each host and check for next URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Using `for` loop:

```
page(){
while true; do
echo "page"
done
}

page2(){
while true; do
echo "page2"
done
}

page3(){
while true; do
echo "page3"
done
}


for i in `cat /path/to/url.txt`
do
        echo $i | awk -F '.' '{print $2}' | xargs
done
```

Comment: Can you please check my update